# Sql select based on the value in other rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select, rows, oracle12c

I have a table like below:

```
DS_no   Value   Language   Nach
1        0        EN        123
2        ABC      EN        123
2        DCEF     EN        123
1        1        EN        122
2        XZU      EN        122
2        SDF      EN        122
```

So i wanted my select statement to check if the value of DS_no which has 1 for every nach. If the value is 1 then it should select all other values for that nach. eg. the ds_no 1 of nach 122. If the ds_no 1 has value 0 then the select should not return any values.

eg: the ds_no 1 of nach 123 has the value 0. so i dont want to select any values of nach 123. but the ds_no 1 of nach 122 has the value 1. so i want to select all the values of nach 122 except the value 1.

Comment: There is no such thing as "first value".  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  Ordering is defined by a column.

Comment: 1 - What's the desired result set ?  2 - Is the last `nach 123` a typo, and should be `nach 122`, ain't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample data as you posted

```
SQL> select * from test;

     DS_NO VALU       NACH
---------- ---- ----------
         1 0           123
         2 abc         123
         2 dcef        123
         1 1           122
         2 xzu         122
         2 sdf         122

6 rows selected.
```

Query that returns what you described, with a side note that you - most probably - made a typo, here:

> so i want to select all the values of nach **123** except the value 1.

`123` should be `122`, I presume.

```
SQL> select ds_no, value, nach
  2  from test a
  3  where value <> '1'
  4    and exists (select null
  5                from test b
  6                where b.nach = a.nach
  7                  and b.value = '1'
  8               );

     DS_NO VALU       NACH
---------- ---- ----------
         2 sdf         122
         2 xzu         122

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no *first* value.  But you can check if *any* value is `0` using `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.nach = t.nach and t2.value = '0'
             );
```

Comment: I have edited my question for the better understanding of 1st value.